# Где исправить настройку в .htaccess

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Всем привет! есть у меня на поддомене сайт с wordpress вида twin.мой_домен
С главной страницей все ок, а при переходе на другие возникает 500 внутренняя ошибка сервера, что означает неправильную настройку .htaccess
сайт находится в корне на хостинге в папке twin (которая находится на одном уровне с public_html)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On   
  RewriteBase /twin/   
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]   
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
  RewriteRule . /twin/index.php [L]  
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Почему все в одной строке? должны быть в отдельных

Comment: где лежит htacces - в /twin ?

Comment: в одной - потому что так упорядочивает кодировщик
"где лежит htacces - в /twin ? " - да

Comment: если вверху правка предполагает решение проблемы, то нет, ничего толком не изменилось

Comment: вверху правка предполагает нормальную читаемость